# Why doesn't C++ give compiler error when you call delete on a non-pointer stack allocated variable?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

One would expect a compiler error when you attempt to delete a non pointer type but it doesn't show, and only crashes at runtime. I wasted entire 2 days believing it was an actual pointer variable and that it was crashing due to a heap corruption elsewhere in the code. Finally accidentally I looked at the declaration of the variable being deleted and found it wasn't a pointer type at all.

Comment: Rudolph, I rechecked with other data types and find what you are saying is correct. I looked into what is special with the particular datatype (a class) I'm facing problem with. It declares a cast operator "operator const PM_UNICHAR*() const;" . So that's why the compiler allows, huh?

Comment: Post some code.  C++ _does_ require a diagnostic (and I've never seen a compiler which didn't give one) if you attempt to delete a non-pointer type (unless it is a class type with an unambiguous user defined conversion to a pointer type).

Comment: Your non-pointer type most probably has an `operator void*` or such member. Otherwise, there is no way (short of a broken compiler) that it would accept a `delete` on something that's not a pointer type or a zero integer literal (which arguably _is_ a pointer). No way.

Comment: Consider an explicit conversion operator if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 7):

> Finally accidentally I looked at the declaration of the variable being deleted and found it wasn't a pointer type at all.

That’s wrong – the compiler *does* give you an error when you attempt to delete a variable that isn’t of type pointer:

```
$ cat test.cpp
int main() {
    int a;
    delete a;
}
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:3:12: error: type 'int' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
     delete a;
            ^
```

However, the compiler *will* accept any type after `delete` which is implicitly convertible to a pointer. This is arguably what we want – implicit cast means we want to “treat this variable as if it were a pointer”. On the other hand, it’s true that this is probably *never* the case in the context of `delete`, and that the C++ language could be more restrictive here.

That said, determining whether a pointer points to valid heap-allocated memory is impossible – it’s equivalent to solving the [*halting problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and thus provably unsolvable in the general case.

Comment: +1 for mentioning halting problem; good to see some computer science on this site.

Comment: Look at my comment in my question.

Answer (score 3):

(Reinterpreting your question slightly to mean warning you when attempting to delete stack-allocated memory:)

That would be extremely difficult, if not impossible, for the compiler to implement. What if, for example, the pointer is passed into a different compilation unit? Or even a different dll /so?

I'm sure all us old cats on this site can understand your frustration, but, I bet you won't ever make the same mistake again!

Comment: Indeed, OP learned a valuable lesson. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of something like this:

```
int a;
int *pa = &a;
delete pa;
```

Then you won't get a compiler error because the above code, while wrong, is not illegal by language definition. However, the compiler may issue a warning if the case is obvious enough (I didn't try, but I guess it won't). A static analyzer tool should detect this though.

If you have something like this, though, there is no way the compiler would know that something is wrong:

```
void foo(int* pa)
{
    delete pa;
}
...
int a;
foo(&a);
```

To detect this, you'll definitely need a good static analyzer such as Coverity. But generally you should avoid patterns like this. Deleting a pointer should always be the responsibility of the class (or other entity) that created it. Even better, you should use smart pointers instead of calling new/delete manually (you'll need a C++11 compatible compiler or use Boost).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you called `delete` on a pointer to a value on the stack. It's perfectly legal to have pointers on the stack that point into the heap, and you can `delete` those just fine.

Using a nice tool like *valgrind* would have caught the fact that you had a bad delete:

[Valgrind User Manual: Illegal frees](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.badfrees)